# Unable to read memory dump with ntsd

Tags: .net, debugging, clr, dump

I'm desperately trying to read a memory dump file (dmp) from a IIS pool process from one of our servers (a w3wp.exe process) but I keep running in to problems. The process started using unusually much CPU power and we had to upgrade the server, so I was asked to investigate this.

I validated the dump file with dumpchk and it seems to be ok!

I open the file like so: ntsd -z w3wp.dmp and I get this:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17336 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\w3wp.DMP]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
Executable search path is:
Windows 8 Version 9600 MP (16 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 6.3.9600.17031 (winblue_gdr.140221-1952)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Wed Apr 29 13:14:23.000 2015 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 1:27:59.628
Process Uptime: 0 days 13:14:23.000
................................................................
................................................................
...........................................
Loading unloaded module list
.....................................
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ntdll.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ntdll.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for KERNELBASE.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for KERNELBASE.dll
ntdll+0x9120a:
00007fff`0efa120a 0000            add     byte ptr [rax],al ds:00000000`00000000=??
0:000>
```

To see what CLR the dump was using when created I do "lm v mclr" and get this:

```
0:000> lm v mclr
start             end                 module name
00007fff`051f0000 00007fff`05b90000   clr        (deferred)
    Image path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Image name: clr.dll
    Timestamp:        Sat Apr 12 04:16:15 2014 (5348A1EF)
    CheckSum:         009A762B
    ImageSize:        009A0000
    File version:     4.0.30319.34209
    Product version:  4.0.30319.34209
    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
0:000>
```

so I try do a symfix and reload clr now I have this:

```
0:000> .cordll -ve -u -l
CLRDLL: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscordacwks.dll:4.0.30319.35317 f:8
doesn't match desired version 4.0.30319.34209 f:8
Automatically loaded SOS Extension
CLRDLL: Loaded DLL C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\sym\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.34209.dll\5348A1EF9a0000\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.34209.dll
CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\sym\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.34209.dll\5348A1EF9a0000\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.34209.dll
0:000>
```

Which is what I expected, the mscordacwks version matches the clr that was used.

Finally i validate sos version (which was auto loaded) by doing .chain this gives me this:

```
0:000> .cordll -ve -u -l
CLRDLL: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscordacwks.dll:4.0.30319.35317 f:8
doesn't match desired version 4.0.30319.34209 f:8
Automatically loaded SOS Extension
CLRDLL: Loaded DLL C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\sym\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.34209.dll\5348A1EF9a0000\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.34209.dll
CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\sym\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.34209.dll\5348A1EF9a0000\mscordacwks_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.34209.dll
0:000>
```

Now as far is a can tell SOS and mscordacwks matches the version of the CLR which was running the code when the dump was taken, but when i try to get the list of managed threads using !threads i get this:

```
0:000> !threads
Failed to load data access DLL, 0x80004005
Verify that 1) you have a recent build of the debugger (6.2.14 or newer)
            2) the file mscordacwks.dll that matches your version of clr.dll is
                in the version directory or on the symbol path
            3) or, if you are debugging a dump file, verify that the file
                mscordacwks_<arch>_<arch>_<version>.dll is on your symbol path.
            4) you are debugging on supported cross platform architecture as
                the dump file. For example, an ARM dump file must be debugged
                on an X86 or an ARM machine; an AMD64 dump file must be
                debugged on an AMD64 machine.

You can also run the debugger command .cordll to control the debugger's
load of mscordacwks.dll.  .cordll -ve -u -l will do a verbose reload.
If that succeeds, the SOS command should work on retry.

If you are debugging a minidump, you need to make sure that your executable
path is pointing to clr.dll as well.
0:000>
```

My last desperate try was to point the executable path to a correct version of the CLR with ".exepath c:\dll" (which contains the correct version of the CLR)
but this did not fix the problem.

The .NET code was compiled running on "any cpu", the server running is x64 and so is the IIS, when looking at det w3wp.exe it also runs x64, so the dump was taken using x64 taskmanager on the server and I use x64 ntsd to debug.

I can't seem to figure out what is going on here and I badly need expert help as I normally do not do this kind of debuggning.

ok.. .so i got debugDiag 2.0 update 1 and used that to take a new full dump from the server. I'm now able to see the managed threds by using !threads. But it seems that all the treads has empty clrstacks, the all look like this:

> 0:045> !clrstack OS Thread Id: 0x23ec (45)
>           Child SP               IP Call Site GetFrameContext failed: 1 0000000000000000 0000000000000000

What going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm your approach seems to be valid and I'm surprised it does not work. There are 2 other ways I know to load a valid SOS into windbg:

- try `!analyse -v` - for .NET dump it should download a valid SOS from Microsoft Symbol Server
- try Andrew Richard's [PDE extension](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=dae128bd454cf957&id=DAE128BD454CF957!7152&ithint=folder,zip&authkey=!ALq3LqMcfgs8JoM) which has a `!loadsos` command

Before performing any of those remember to unload all SOS extension you loaded in your WinDbg session (`.unchain sos`)

You may also have a look at links in [my note about debugging CLR with WinDbg](https://github.com/lowleveldesign/debug-recipes/blob/master/debugging-using-windbg/windbg-clr-debugging.md).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this when I get to work tomorrow. Meanwhile I have been using dottrace, but its not giving me the desired results.

Comment: I managed to get a dump working, but now I see empty clrstack... I edited my question.

Comment: @iCediCe The CLRStack error is normal for non-managed threads. Try `~*e!CLRStack` to see call stacks for all threads and find those which are interesting for you.